# Signal in wgetnstr function

Tags: c, ncurses

I have `wgetnstr(input, str, MSG_SIZE)` and when I write something and press C-c it literally prints ^C, instead of singal. I even handled this signal explicitly with `signal(SIGINT, handler)` but nothing seems to work. Is it even possible to handle signals inside of ncurses' functions?

Comment: Please provide a complete [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) given, but echoing controls like that would happen if one used [`cbreak`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-cbreak_nocbreak) or [`raw`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-raw_noraw).  The default behavior in ncurses (any curses implementation) lets `SIGINT` kill the application.

There's a summary of signal behavior for ncurses in the [`initscr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_initscr.3x.html#h3-Signal-Handlers) manual page.  Likewise, [`wgetnstr`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) manual page documents the control characters which it respects.  The description there gives a hint that writing your own variation would be not difficult:

> The function ***`getstr`*** is equivalent to a series of calls to ***`getch`***,  until a  newline or carriage return is received (the terminating character is not included in the returned string).  The resulting value is placed in the area pointed to by the character pointer str, followed by a `NUL`.

Comment: Yeah, I rewrote function for my purposes, forgot to delete thread. Thanks!